# Remote Desktop (Windows 10 to Ubuntu 20.04) unable to use GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, windows-10, remote-desktop, nvidia-geforce

I am trying to visualise 3D models using ParaView on my new work PC, which has **Ubuntu 20.04** installed and is equipped with an **NVIDIA RTX3080 GPU**. Visualisation of the data when I am in the office is no problem. However, when working from home I also have to make some visualisations. ParaView starts, I can load data, but the RenderView is not displaying anything except for a coordinate orientation (X Y Z). After some time it gives the message:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-luuk'
```

In addition, when adding/removing a view element in Paraview, such as the Memory Inspector, nothing is visible to me at all and instead I **look "through"** the Paraview client to my desktop as if the entire RenderView was cut out. However, when I select "Save Screenshot" in Paraview, I get a nice image of my model **as if it was rendered**... I guess this means that the images are rendered but not transmitted to my screen at home?

I assume it is a problem between the Windows Remote Desktop Client and the NVIDIA GPU, because running `sudo nvidia-detector` when remotely connected gives the following error:

```
luuk@holykauw:~/Documents/ETH/ErosionModelling/quicktest$ sudo nvidia-detector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/nvidia-detector", line 8, in <module>
    a = NvidiaDetection(printonly=True, verbose=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.getData()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py", line 163, in getData
    driver_version = self.__get_value_from_name(stripped_package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/NvidiaDetector/nvidiadetector.py", line 92, in __get_value_from_name
    v = int(name)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'server'
```

Additionally, running `sudo nvidia-settings` gives:

```
luuk@holykauw:~/Documents/ETH/ErosionModelling/quicktest$ sudo nvidia-settings -V
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

I don't know what this error means or how I can solve it.
Because this does not show errors when called locally from the PC. I am relatively new to both Linux/Ubuntu and Paraview. Does anyone have a clue if these errors are fixable? I should note that the remote desktop connection is rendering slowly in general: e.g. the desktop background, web pages and such are loaded at speeds as if we were two decades back in time. It really slows down my research work.

I would really appreciate any help or advice that you may have. I'll be happy to provide additional information should you require it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution :

reboot

init 3

```
sudo rmmod nvidia_drm
sudo rmmod nvidia_modeset
sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm
```

then, unload nvidia

```
sudo rmmod nvidia
apt remove --purge nvidia*
sudo reboot

ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

```
nvidia-smi 

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 530.41.03              Driver Version: 530.41.03    CUDA Version: 12.1     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                  Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf            Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P2000                    On | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 44%   30C    P8                4W /  75W|     71MiB /  5120MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1116      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           64MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1249      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).